# How to add a variable to javascript sticky panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

It might be over kill but this works. I copied the first variable in its entirety and and gave it a new name. Also, delinked it from call_files/header.html and css/header.css files. Instead, I linked it to the layout.css which governs the appearance of the second menu. I'm sure there is a way to stream line it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        var stickyPanelOptions = {
            topPadding: 0,
            afterDetachCSSClass: "BoxGlow_Grey2",
            savePanelSpace: true,
            onDetached: function (detachedPanel, spacerPanel) {
                call_files/header.html(call_files/header.html() + " has been detached!");
                css/header.css("background-color", "#1000ff");
            },
            onReAttached: function (detachedPanel) {
                call_files/header.html(call_files/header.html().replace(" has been detached!", ""));
            },
            parentSelector: null
        };

        var secondstickyPanelOptions = {
            topPadding: 150,
            savePanelSpace: true,
            onDetached: function (detachedPanel, spacerPanel) {
                detachedPanel.html(detachedPanel.html() + " has been detached!");
                layout.css("background-color", "#ffffff");
            },
            onReAttached: function (detachedPanel) {
                detachedPanel.html(detachedPanel.html().replace(" has been detached!", ""));
            },
            parentSelector: null
        };

        // multiple panel example (you could also use the class ".stickypanel" to select both)
        $("#Panel1").stickyPanel(stickyPanelOptions);

        $("#Panel2").stickyPanel(secondstickyPanelOptions);

        $("#Panel3").stickyPanel(stickyPanelOptions);

        $("#UnstickPanel3").click(function () {
            $("#Panel3").stickyPanel("unstick");
        });

        stickyPanelOptions.parentSelector = "#AbsoluteDiv";
        $("#Panel4").stickyPanel(stickyPanelOptions);

        stickyPanelOptions.parentSelector = "#NormalDiv";
        $("#Panel5").stickyPanel(stickyPanelOptions);
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="Panel1" class="stickyPanel">
 <div class="headerBGdiv"> </div>
 <?php include('../call_files/pagesheader.html');?>
</div>


<div id="Panel2" class="stickyPanel">
 <div id="navbar2">
  <ul id="tabs">
   <li><a href="#buyersguide">Buyer's Guide</a></li>
   <li><a href="#restrictions">Export Restrictions</a></li>
   <li><a href="#IR101">Infrared 101</a></li>
   <li><a href="#whitepages">White Pages</a></li>
   <li><a href="#terms">Terminology</a></li>
   <li><a href="#news">Newsroom</a></li>
   <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>  
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What library do you use? [This one](https://github.com/donnyv/sticky-panel)?

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//use.edgefonts.net/cabin;source-sans-pro:n2,i2,n3,n4,n6,n7,n9.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.stickypanel.js"></script>

Comment: all original files here: https://github.com/donnyv/sticky-panel

Comment: original demo here:http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/donnyv/sticky-panel/blob/master/jquery.stickyPanel/Main.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try This it uses separate config options for each panel.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        var stickyPanelOptions = {
            topPadding: 0,
            savePanelSpace: true,
            onDetached: function (detachedPanel, spacerPanel) {
                call_files/header.html(call_files/header.html() + " has been detached!");
                css/header.css("background-color", "#1000ff");
            },
            secondStickyPanelOptions = stickyPanelOptions,
            onReAttached: function (detachedPanel) {
                call_files/header.html(call_files/header.html().replace(" has been detached!", ""));
            },
            parentSelector: null
        };

        secondStickyPanelOptions.topPadding = 100;

        // multiple panel example (you could also use the class ".stickypanel" to select both)
        $("#Panel1").stickyPanel(stickyPanelOptions);

        $("#Panel2").stickyPanel(secondStickyPanelOptions);

        $("#Panel3").stickyPanel(stickyPanelOptions);

        $("#UnstickPanel3").click(function () {
            $("#Panel3").stickyPanel("unstick");
        });

        stickyPanelOptions.parentSelector = "#AbsoluteDiv";
        $("#Panel4").stickyPanel(stickyPanelOptions);

        stickyPanelOptions.parentSelector = "#NormalDiv";
        $("#Panel5").stickyPanel(stickyPanelOptions);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's not working, even when I change  $("#Panel1").stickyPanel(secondStickyPanelOptions); to  $("#Panel2").stickyPanel(secondStickyPanelOptions);